# How to extract unique values from pandas column where values are in list

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe, unique

I want to extract unique cities from city column in pandas dataframe. City column has values in list. How would I extract the cities frequency like:

```
Lahore  3
Karachi 2
Sydney  1
```

etc.

Sample dataframe:

```
    Name  Age      City
a   jack   34    [Sydney,Delhi]
b   Riti   31    [Lahore,Delhi]
c   Aadi   16  [New York, Karachi, Lahore]
d  Mohit   32     [Peshawar,Delhi, Karachi]
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let us try `explode` + `value_counts`

```
out = df.City.explode().value_counts()
```